# Subquery with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, where-clause

There's a poorly designed table in my database which contains some information I need to extract. Supose I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT I FROM X WHERE X.A = FOO AND X.B = KEY),
    (SELECT J FROM X WHERE X.A = BAR AND X.B = KEY),
    (SELECT K FROM X WHERE X.A = BAZ AND X.B = KEY)
```

I need to expand the query to select some other fields. My first idea was this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT I FROM X WHERE X.A = FOO AND X.B = KEY),
    (SELECT J FROM X WHERE X.A = BAR AND X.B = KEY),
    (SELECT K FROM X WHERE X.A = BAZ AND X.B = KEY)
    (SELECT L, M, N FROM X WHERE X.A = QUX AND X.B = KEY)
```

However, i get an error stating that a subquery that fetches columns can only fetch one column, unless it is introduced with an EXISTS clause. I could write the last subquery as such:

```
    (SELECT L, M, N FROM X AS OUTER
    WHERE EXISTS 
        (SELECT ID FROM X WHERE X.A = QUX AND X.B = KEY AND X.ID = OUTER.ID)(
```

Won't this solution be needlessly heavy? Is there another solution to this?

EDIT:

I need to extract the information into a single row. I also should mention that there is no guarantee that every X.A is present (There might be keys that only have FOO, others that have BAR and QUX, etc), so joining is not possible.

EDIT: @Saharsh Shah requested some sample data:

```
|X.B |X.A|X.I     |X.J     |X.K     |X.L     |X.M     |X.N     |
|KEY1|FOO|ICONTENT|        |        |        |        |        |
|KEY1|BAR|        |JCONTENT|        |        |        |        |
|KEY1|BAZ|        |        |KCONTENT|        |        |        |
|KEY1|QUX|        |        |        |LCONTENT|MCONTENT|NCONTENT|
|KEY2|BAR|        |JCONTENT|        |        |        |        |
|KEY3|FOO|ICONTENT|        |        |        |        |        |
|KEY3|QUX|        |        |        |LCONTENT|MCONTENT|NCONTENT|
```

And the expected result:
For key 1:

```
X.I     |X.J     |X.K     |X.L     |X.M     |X.N     |
ICONTENT|JCONTENT|KCONTENT|LCONTENT|MCONTENT|NCONTENT|
```

For key 2:

```
X.I     |X.J     |X.K     |X.L     |X.M     |X.N     |
        |JCONTENT|        |        |        |        |
```

For key 3:

```
X.I     |X.J     |X.K     |X.L     |X.M     |X.N     |
ICONTENT|        |        |LCONTENT|MCONTENT|NCONTENT|
```

Comment: I edited the queries to fix the parameters. The first query column should be X.A on all subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **CASE** statement to validate conditions

Try this:

```
SELECT X.B, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN X.A = FOO THEN I ELSE '' END) AS I, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN X.A = BAR THEN J ELSE '' END) AS J, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN X.A = BAZ THEN K ELSE '' END) AS K, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN X.A = QUX THEN L ELSE '' END) AS L, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN X.A = QUX THEN M ELSE '' END) AS M, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN X.A = QUX THEN N ELSE '' END) AS N
FROM X 
WHERE X.B = KEY
GROUP BY X.B;
```

Comment: @ez pz this solution should work then for your question.

Comment: This returns multiple rows, determined by X.A. My idea is to group the different columns into a single row.

Comment: It has been added to my post.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in 2 ways : -

```
select i, j , k , l , m, n
from x 
where i in (select i from x where x.a = 'FOO' or x.B = 'KEY') and 
j in (select j from x where x.b = 'BAR' or x.B = 'KEY') and 
k in (select k from x where x.c = 'BAZ' or x.B = 'KEY')
```

or the other way is :

```
select (select count(i) from x where x.a = 'foo') as i  , (select count(j) from x where x.b in ('KEY', 'BAR') as j , (select count(k) from x where x.c = 'BAZ' and x.B = 'KEY') as k , l, m , n
from x
```

Comment: The first query you posted doesn't fetch the L, M and N columns, and the second query doesn't work because I need to aggregate the results of the subqueries into a single row. I also fixed a mistake on the query columns, could you reread my queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use derived table as this

```
Select foo.I, bar.J , baz.K, qux.L, qux.M ,qux.N  from x
left outer join (Select * from x where x.A = foo) foo on foo.b = x.b
left outer join (Select * from x where x.A = bar) bar on bar.b = x.b
left outer join (Select * from x where x.A = baz) baz on baz.b = x.b
left outer join (Select * from x where x.A = qux) qux on qux.b = x.b
where x.B = key
```

if you are sure that data with a=foo , ... exists, inner join is also applicable

Comment: This fails because a key may not have all FOO, BAR, BAZ and QUX entries. In this case, a key which does not have a QUX entry won't fetch the FOO, BAR and BAZ tables.